# Error: "Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "..." is not a valid regular expression

Tags: regex, google-sheets, syntax-error, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have some problem righting a regex on Google sheet.

I have in one cell a text with several informations :

```
D ID : d_************
T ID : t_************
Date : **/**/2019
O ID : ************
```

And I'd like to have every ID in different cells.

I tried this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(L9,"\[(?<=D ID : )(.*)(?=T)]\")
```

But I got the error in the title

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: What does the error mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(SPLIT(A1; CHAR(10)); 
 REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(A1; CHAR(10)); "ID")); ": (.*)"))
```

[image: 0]